# sIFR 3 Uppercase

Tags: sifr

Can someone please explain how can I implement text-transform: uppercase; feature with sIFR 3?

On the doc, it explains how to use it but I really don't know how to implement it. Can someone provide an example?

> Specifes text transformation. This is
>   handled by sIFR because Flash does not
>   support this natively. It is applied
>   to all text, if you want to apply it
>   to a specific element you'll need to
>   use the modifyContent function. If
>   sIFR.forceTextTransform is false, sIFR
>   will not perform the transformation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would add the `text-transform` property to the CSS rules in the `css` property of the options object passed to the `sIFR.replace` method (phew!).

An example:

```
sIFR.replace(myFont, {
  selector: 'h2',
  css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 20px; color: #008cba; text-transform: uppercase; }',
  wmode: 'transparent'
});
```